# A tiny CSS margin issue

Tags: html, css, whitespace

the code is not so small to paste it here, so I'm including a [codepen link](https://codepen.io/GUNSY/pen/XWJrgJR),
but I'm sure its easy to read and understand. 
**The Problem is:** There's extra empty space below `body` and I learned that it's caused by the `body` not expanding to fit in the `itemsbox` div's 10% margin on top and bottom, I want to know why it is not expanding and what can be done to make it expand so as to fit the `itemsbox` including it's margin.

Additional info: The body expands to fit `itemsbox` including it's margin on top and bottom **if** there's 3 or more rows of `products` in the `itemsbox` excluding the `productdummies`, you can copy the following `product` code and add it before the first `productdummy`, to see this in action.
 Add 5 copies of this code.

```
<div class="product" id="2155640">
  <div class="product-imagecontainer"><img class="product-image" src=""></div>
  <p class="product-name">Ninja Melk</p>
  <p class="product-price">$24</p>
  <button class="product-button-addtocart" onclick="addtocart">Add To Cart</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

no needed of line min-height in #itemsbox

and remove two line in file html

```
 <div class="product product-dummy"></div>
 <div class="product product-dummy"></div>
```

Comment: Those `product dummies` are important for the flexbox to work properly.

Comment: I didn't want to limit the `itemsbox` to a specific height, but I wanted to set a base height as well so I used min-height